# Is it bad practice for a function to return different types?

Tags: python, function

Let's say we have a function that detects multiples of 3:

```
t1 = (1, 2, 5)
t2 = (3, 6, 9)

def find3(t):
    return [x for x in t if not x % 3] or None
```

My initial inclination, having not worked in any professional programming environment, would be to return `None` if `t1` is passed in, and `[3, 6, 9]` if `t2` is passed in.

However, I've seen multiple people say that functions should always return the same type. That means returning `[]` instead of `None`.

Not only is `[]` more memory-intensive, but it also seems less clear. If I call `find3()` on a dataset, and there are no multiples, I'd rather see the word `None` than an empty list, because it resembles real-life language more.

Yes, I know this can cause problems if the results of `find3()` are used in a different location, but all it takes for problems to disappear is a simple `if find3()` check. So why/is it preferable to return `[]` in all cases?

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, but returning None is fine. PS, you can shorten it to `return [x for x in t if not x % 3] or None`

Comment: It's a matter of taste but other languages like e.g. Java also return null references/null pointers on error instead of valid references/pointers.

Comment: Normally, you're right - creating a function that sometimes returns a string and sometimes returns an integer would be bad practice. However, `None` is special in Python, as it is of the `NoneType` - it is specifically intended for variables that don't currently have a value of the type you'd expect them to have and so your code is fine.

Comment: Personally, I'd just return the empty `list` in this case. If the caller cares about empty vs. not empty, then they can test `if retval:` and it works whether it's an empty `list` or `None`. But a lot of the time, code can run without explicit tests by simply looping over "whatever results were received", and `for x in retval:` without a preliminary `if retval:` only works for the empty `list`, not for `None`. Make it easier to avoid constant return value tests and just return the `list`, empty or not.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Python has exceptions for actual failure. Anything that is returning flag values to indicate actual unexpected failure is just delaying the error until the value is used, when they could indicate the problem more directly and immediately with an exception.

Comment: Returning None is more memory intensive. You create an empty list regardless. To return None, you check it, discard it, get a reference to None, then return that, instead of just returning the list you already made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer an empty list over `None`, well, I can't say that, it depends on what the problem is.

**Why should I have a `[]` (empty list)?**

Usually when you need to do some operation after this, let's say we want to `append` an extra value.

With `None`:

```
def find3(t):
    return [x for x in t if not x % 3] or None
l = find3(t1)
l.append(1)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

With `[]`:

```
def find3(t):
    return [x for x in t if not x % 3]
l = find3(t1)
l.append(1)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[1]
```

As you see, `None` gets you a error.

And also, you can have a cleaner code with getting an output of `[]`.

**Why should I have a `None`?**

Well, usually when you finish the code with one simple function (as you shown us), to make it clearer to see for users of the code (I mean by users as people who never coded).

Both ways you can do the same statement and pass:

```
def find3(t):
    return [x for x in t if not x % 3] or None
l = find3(t1)
if l:
    print('Success')
```

And:

```
def find3(t):
    return [x for x in t if not x % 3]
l = find3(t1)
if l:
    print('Success')
```

Also, for `append`ing this, you could do:

```
def find3(t):
    return [x for x in t if not x % 3] or None
l = find3(t1) or []
l.append(1)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

`or` is magical...

**Summary:**

At the end, it is all your decision (as SO describes this, primarily opinion-based), you can decide whatever you want, nobody will care (when you don't show it public) how disastrous your code is, if it works, it is all okay, if it doesn't, it is all not okay.

Comment: Not to mention that as long as it's clearly documented and works as intended, nobody will really complain. Documentation is very important.

Comment: All the examples you use for returning `None` work just as well with an empty list. `None` doesn't win those cases.

Comment: @user2357112 I am really saying that it is easier with `[]`

Answer (score 2):

### Rule of thumb

Given some kind of search function...

A failure to find a single element should return `None`;

A failure to find any element when many are expected should return `[]`.

### Explanation

Some built-in methods such as [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) return `None` to indicate some form of negation or failure, in that case meaning *nothing found*.

Although, in your specific case, the negation can perfectly be represented by an empty list `[]` due to it being [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/5079316), so there is not benefit to returning `None`.

The list-equivalent to `re.search`, that is [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), does exactly that. It returns `[]` when there is no match.

There is even a practical reason not to return `None`. Consider this code...

```
for x in find3([1, 2, 4]):
    ...
```

This will raise a `TypeError` which is counter-intuitive and you would have to fix it by undoing what the function did.

```
for x in find3([1, 2, 4]) or []:
    ...
```

This shows that returning `None` is more of a pain than anything here.